# XSLT document() not working whre used with javascript xsltProcessor

Tags: xml, xslt, document

This seems to work fine when processing the document in the browser

```
<select class="form-control">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('Options.xml')/Options/Option"/>
  </select>
```

But not when I try to process it again using Javascript xsltProcessor.

Any clue anyone?

Javascript:

```
let xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
const xmlResponseDocument = window.location.href;
const xmlContent = loadXMLDoc(xmlResponseDocument);
const path = '/Doc/Records';
const xslDocument = loadXMLDoc(pageTemplate);
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslDocument);
const parser = new DOMParser();
target = '#main-content';

function xContent(e) {
var xml = xmlContent.documentElement;
var content = getElementByXpath(path);
xAttributesArray(e);
resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(content, document);
contentTarget = document.querySelector(target);
contentTarget.innerHTML = '';
contentTarget.appendChild(resultDocument);
}

function xAttributesArray(e) {
var attrArray = Array.from(e.attributes);
var i = 0;
qrStr = '';
attrArray.filter(attrArray => attrArray.name.startsWith('x-')).forEach(function (elm) {
    var attname = elm.name.substring(2).replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, m => m.toUpperCase());
    xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, attname, elm.value);
    if (i > 0) { qrStr += '&'; }
    qrStr += attname + '=' + elm.value.replace('#', '');
    i++;
}
);
return attrArray;
}

function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);

xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function getElementByXpath(path) {
try {
    //let xmlContent = loadXMLDoc(xmlResponseDocument);
    return document.evaluate(path, xmlContent, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
} catch (e) {
    return e;
}

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/Test/Index.xslt'?>
<Doc>
<Records>
  <Record ID="225">
    <Room ID="2" Num="101" />
    <Week>25</Week>
    <Yr>2020</Yr>
    <WeekIn>25</WeekIn>
    <StayWeeks>1</StayWeeks>
    <LastName>John</LastName>
    <FirstName>Doe</FirstName>
  </Record>
  <Record ID="226">
    <Room ID="2" Num="101" />
    <Week>26</Week>
    <Yr>2020</Yr>
    <WeekIn>26</WeekIn>
    <StayWeeks>1</StayWeeks>
    <LastName>Jane</LastName>
    <FirstName>Doe</FirstName>
    <Color>magenta</Color>
  </Record>
  <Record ID="227">
    <Room ID="2" Num="101" />
    <Week>27</Week>
    <Yr>2020</Yr>
    <StayWeeks>0</StayWeeks>
  </Record>
  <Record ID="228">
    <Room ID="2" Num="101" />
    <Week>28</Week>
    <Yr>2020</Yr>
    <WeekIn>28</WeekIn>
    <StayWeeks>2</StayWeeks>
    <LastName>David</LastName>
    <FirstName>Davies</FirstName>
    <Color>magenta</Color>
  </Record>
  <Record ID="230">
    <Room ID="2" Num="101" />
    <Week>30</Week>
    <Yr>2020</Yr>
    <WeekIn>30</WeekIn>
    <StayWeeks>1</StayWeeks>
    <LastName>Marcus</LastName>
    <FirstName>Marco</FirstName>
    <Color>magenta</Color>
  </Record>
  <Record ID="233">
    <Room ID="2" Num="101" />
    <Week>33</Week>
    <Yr>2020</Yr>
    <StayWeeks>0</StayWeeks>
  </Record>
  <Record ID="234">
    <Room ID="2" Num="101" />
    <Week>34</Week>
    <Yr>2020</Yr>
    <StayWeeks>0</StayWeeks>
  </Record>
  <Record ID="325">
    <Room ID="3" Num="102" />
    <Week>25</Week>
    <Yr>2020</Yr>
    <StayWeeks>0</StayWeeks>
  </Record>
</Records>
</Doc>
```

And the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="Id"/>
<xsl:param name="View"/>

<xsl:template match="Doc">
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <div id="main-content">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Records"/>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">let pageTemplate = '/Test/Index.xslt'</script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/Test/test.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Records">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$View='form'">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[@ID=$Id]" mode="form"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <select class="form-control">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('Options.xml')/Options/Option"/>
    </select>
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Record"/>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Record">
 <tr onclick="xContent(this)" x-id="{@ID}" x-view="form">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="Room/@Num"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="Week"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Record" mode="form">
<div>
  <input value="{Room/@Num}"></input>
  <input value="{LastName}"></input>
  <input value="{FirstName}"></input>
  <select class="form-control">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('Options.xml')/Options/Option"/>
  </select>
</div>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Option">
<option>
  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
</option>
 </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete code samples of XML, XSLT, Javascript to allow others to reproduce. Also how exactly does it fail, which error do you get from which browser(s) exactly?

Comment: It fails simply because it is simply not showing the content of the select. Sorry I tried to paste the xml and xslt but it throws error in here

Comment: Use the edit link https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62609647/edit to edit your question and to show minimal samples of XML, XSLT and Javascript there, together with information about the browsers where it fails. Have you checked the error console of the browsers?

Comment: I have managed to copy it now. Thanks The browser is Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a long standing, known bug in Chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8441 and WebKit https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60276 that they don't intend to fix.